# Intuitive explanation of why a large spread makes scheduling problems harder

Tags: algorithms

The problem of minimizing weighted flow-time (min-WPFT) is defined as follows:

- We are given a set $J$ of $n$ jobs, each job $j$ having a release time $r_j$, a processing time $p_j$, and a weight $w_j$.
- We want to find a preemptive scheduling of the jobs on a single machine. (Preemptive meaning we are allowed to halt and resume jobs.)
- For a given schedule $\mathbf{S}$, each job $j$ has a completion time $C_j$, which is simply the time at which it is completed in $\mathbf{S}$, and a flow-time defined as $C_j - r_j$, which is how long it was waiting to be completed after being released.
- Our goal is to minimize $\sum_{j \in J} w_j (C_j - r_j)$

[Here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.09885) is the paper I am currently reading about this problem. Although I don't think anyone answering this problem has to even look at it to provide an answer.

It turns out that for this scheduling problem, what makes this problem difficult is when there is a large spread. We define the spread of the processing times $\hat{P}$ as $\hat{P} := \frac{\max p_j}{\min p_j}$ and the spread of the weights $\hat{W}$ as $\hat{W} := \frac{\max w_j}{\min w_j}$.

The paper I linked shows that there is a polynomial time $O(1)$ approximation for min-WFPT even when the spreads aren't polynomial in the input size. However, before this paper, there was only a pseudo-polynomial time $O(1)$ approximation for min-WFPT. This pseudo-polynomial time algorithm was polynomial in $n$, the number of jobs, and $\hat{P}$, the spread of processing times. (So in other words, if $\hat{P}$ happened to be exponential in the size of the input, this pseudo-polynomial time algorithm would not run in polynomial time in the size of the input.)

The questions I have is: **Intuitively speaking, why does a large spread make scheduling problems hard?**

I provide this example specifically because it is what I'm looking at right now, but I believe I have seen different scheduling problems in the past that were also hardest when the instance had a large spread, whether that be in the weights or the processing times.

My thinking right now is that when all the jobs are very similar, it is easier to get a good approximation because there are less sort of tricky, nonobvious ways of ordering the jobs. This being because an arbitrary job would typically be replaceable by another arbitrary job in a given schedule.

I was hoping some more experienced people could affirm this or affirm whether it even makes sense to generalize difficulty due to a large spread in the first place to most scheduling problems. Thanks for the help!